# SonarQube 6.5 does not open to the localhost. SonarQube was added to Angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, sonarqube, angular-cli, sonarqube-web

I added SonarQube 6.5 to Angular 10. SonarQube starts, but does not scan the project.   In package.json I have information:  "sonar": "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=front -Dsonar.sources=src"

Someone knows why SonarQube does not scan my project?

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What does "will not run" mean?  Show exactly what you did, and exactly what happens.

Comment: I updated my request.

Comment: I have to emphasize again, you need to provide more details. We have no idea what "does not scan the project" means. Tell us exactly what you did, and exactly what happens.